# Custom distribution for starting locations in GIS space Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am creating a model where I have a population of agents in GIS space. I also have regions which are at a set GIS point.
I want to create a custom distribution for the initial model so that the origin value for the individuals in the population is one of the regions and this is the place the agents start at.
I have created an option list and assigned value to it for the distribution. However, it cannot convert from origin (type form option list) to a region.
The value for the Origin, type region, for the population is the custom distribution but it throws

[the custom distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0iIu.png) 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Origin to Region.

How can I create a list of starting regions and assign them according to a distribution to my population??

Answer (score 0):

You should write a custom function that converts your OL names (String) to the actual GIS region objects. In it, use a `switch` statement to map every given OL entry to the exact GIS region it represents. Return that GIS region.

Your function will take an OL entry as the input arg and return a GIS region that depends on the given OL entry.

Let's say you have an OL as below:

[image]

then your function should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have not used a switch before or custom function (new to anylogic, done a little bit of java), is there an example you could point me to?

Comment: So i have used this code to define my origin for my population. 'OriginToRegion(OriginDistribution());'  then i have tried to write a switch statement in a function called OriginToRegion 'switch(startingPosition) {
case AR:
    Region AR1;
    break;
case M:
    Region M1;
    break;
case GP:
   Region GP1;
    break;
    
case MK:
   Region MK1;
    break;
    
case PL:
    Region PL1;
    break;
}
return Region;' The takes in from an options list called startingPosition which has the options.

Comment: This then throws 3 errors 1. Description: Region cannot be resolved to a variable. Location: ssconflict1/Main/OriginToRegion - Function. 2.Description: startingPosition cannot be resolved to a variable. Location: ssconflict1/Main/OriginToRegion - Function  3.Description: The method OriginToRegion() in the type Main is not applicable for the arguments (startingPosition). Location: ssconflict1/Main/population - Person

Comment: Hi Bethany, please see extended answer above. Please mark the answer as "helpful" if it solved the problem so future users can find it faster.

Comment: Thanks, that has helped, although the break line is unreachable and I believe this is because it stops at a return statement. It seems to work once you remove it.

Comment: true, didn't test it. If it helped, please mark the reply as "useful" (little up arrow next to it). It will help other people find this question easier in the future :-)

Comment: I have but my rating doesn't count as I have only just joined and have no reputation. Thanks for your help